# Ionic Content bottom effect

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I used Ionic 3 for my university project. I'm trying to find some tutorial for an animation like the one below, but I can't find any tutorial. I want to know how to add an effect like this. The animation/effect I'm talking about is the one showing when you reach the end of a list. For example the Facebook and Gmail app use an animation like this. Does anyone know how to add this to Ionic 3? Thanks

video example : https://streamable.com/w803y

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 0px; position: relative; padding-bottom: 177.778%;"><iframe src="https://streamable.com/s/w803y/tplzas" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"></iframe></div>
```

[image: Example effect]

Comment: But there is no any animation in your example. I'm not using Facebook and Gmail, can you clarify what kind of animation do you mean?

Comment: look at uber app/ whats app/ they all of app are using some scrolling effect  like this my image. move the content display transparency effect.

Comment: actually i don't know how to explain this effect you can simply understand it look at my recommended app

Comment: can u provide some video please?

Comment: It's a default wave animation on the bottom of the screen of Android. If I'm not mistaken this is a default animation on listviews on Android. It's should  be possible to recreate this though with Javascript/CSS

Comment: @AntoshaShmonoff Sir. look at this video https://streamable.com/w803y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This scrolling effect is available in Android platform since **Lollipop** release. This was part of **Material Design** release.

> This effect is only available on Android platform **NOT** on iOS

Check this *New end-of-scroll animations (and a new look for Gmail)* at link when it was release: https://gizmodo.com/the-best-of-android-lollipop-in-8-gifs-1652428837

Check this video here : https://youtu.be/ydFKEMxEywE?t=48

You **can not get this effect in your Ionic app** because this is Android's native effect.

> **How to get this effect in Android app?**

1. Either develop pure Android App
2. Or develop app using **React Native**, this will help you get **effect only in Android device NOT on iOS device**

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use Animate.css easily in your applicatin.
First you need to install

```
npm install --save css-animator
```

After that include 'AnimationService, AnimatesDirective' in your app module

```
import { AnimationService, AnimatesDirective } from 'css-animator';
```

include AnimatesDirective in declarations

```
declarations: [
AnimatesDirective,
...,
```

and AnimationService in your provider

```
providers: [
AnimationService,
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
```

You need to link Animate.css in you index.html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
```

Here is a simple code

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ModalController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {ContactPage} from '../contact/contact';
import { AnimationService, AnimationBuilder } from 'css-animator';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
@ViewChild('myElement') myElem;
  private animator: AnimationBuilder;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalController: ModalController, animationService: AnimationService) {
this.animator = animationService.builder();
  }
  animateElem() {
    this.animator.setType('bounceInUp').show(this.myElem.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button (click)="animateElem()">Animate it!</button>
<ion-card #myElement>
  <ion-card-header>My Animation Card</ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>So much awesome content and animations. AMAZING!</ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic3-animation) i have created a stackblitz repo for refrence. You can call function in scroll event.

Comment: This is not correct answer. Are you sure your answer is correct for this question? He is asking scroll animation but in your demo I can not see that.

Comment: I have edited my answer. We can use this event on scrolling event.

Comment: Still not the correct answer. You are not getting the exact requirement. Check this video : https://streamable.com/w803y

Comment: @ZearaeZ Hi Sir.  your answer is not  support for my question

Comment: @core114 check out my answer. Unfortunately you can not get this effect in Ionic.